# Sql joins with the last entry

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've have an sql database similar to the following:

[image]

Note: there is a missing column personId in event.

There are tables: Person that has many Events. Travel, playsBasquetBall and playsFooball are types of event.

How can I make a query that retunrs, for each person its current place (last travel event) and type of the last match (basquetball or football)?
Is theres somehow that I can do to skip the subqueries like the following (a part than denormalizing tables)?

```
SELECT person.*, 
       ( SELECT place 
         FROM Travel 
         JOIN Event event ON place.id = event.id 
                          AND event.personId = person.id
       )
```

Example data:

```
Person(1)
Person(2)
Event(1, 20001001)
Travel(1, "Barcelona")
Event(2, 20011001)
Travel(2, "Paris")
Event(3, 2041001)
Travel(3, "Girona")
Event(4, 20001001)
Travel(4, "Barcelona")
```

Example response:

```
1, 4, Barcelona
2, null, null
```

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result. I'm afraid you'll need subqueries. What's your issue with subqueries?

Comment: Just added an example.
My database is basically events and I think that this kind of sub-query will cause a problem with query speed.

Comment: Does the table "Event" have a column named "personId"?

Comment: Yes, sorry, its missing on the diagram

Comment: Without a column to link either the "Travel" or "Event" table to the "Person" table, the problem cannot be solved.

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming the table "Event" have a column named "personId"

This can be done using Multiple `LEFT JOIN`s :

```
SELECT p.id, e2.id as event_id, t.place
FROM Person p
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT personId, MAX(date) AS latest_date
  FROM Event
  GROUP BY personId
) e ON e.personId = p.id
LEFT JOIN Event e2 ON e.personId = e2.personId
                   AND e.latest_date = e2.date
LEFT JOIN travel t on t.eventId = e2.id;
```

For this simple data :

```
create table Person (
  id int
);

insert into Person values
(1),(2);

create table Event (
  id int,
  personId int,
  date int
);

insert into Event values (1, 1, 2001001),(2, 1, 2001101),(3, 1, 2001201),(4, 1, 2001301);

create table Travel (
  eventId int,
  place varchar(20)
);

insert into Travel values (1, 'Barcelona'), (2, 'Paris'), (3, 'Girona'), (4, 'Barcelona');
```

Results :

```
id  event_id    place
1   4           Barcelona
2   null        null
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/0IrJEQUZ)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use ’distinct on’ in a sub select left join.

Something like this

```
select person.id
       _.place
from person
left join (
    select distinct on (event.person_id),
           event.person_id,
           travel.place
    from event
    join travel on travel.event_id = event.id
    order by person_id, date desc
) _ on _.person_id = person.id
```

Would need to do similar for the sport event tables maybe using a ’union all’